# Change background-position of an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hello good afternoon community.
I want to move your background-position in xa this image to act as a video
but do not mistake that I have
Thanks before hand

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.imagen').mouseenter(function(){
        var numero = -535;
        var suma;
        for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            $(this).css({'backgroundPosition': suma+"px 0px"}, "-10");
            suma = numero * i;
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kiokotzu/zw8rB/

Comment: sorry is this link
http://jsfiddle.net/kiokotzu/zw8rB/4/

Answer (score 1):

you should use `background-position` not `backgroudPosition` in `''` and there was a syntax error as you did not close brackets

http://jsfiddle.net/zw8rB/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.imagen').mouseenter(function(){
        var numero = -535;
        var suma;
        for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            $(this).css({'background-position': suma+"px 0px"}, "-10");
            suma = numero * i;
        }
    }
);
    });
```

Comment: Hushme how do I change the background position from time to time?

Comment: you mean you want a mouseout function too?

Comment: I need a function that changes the background position from time to time to act as a video

Comment: do u mean like that http://www.zoompanningeffectslider.com/type_FullWidth.html

Comment: something like this http://larealpari.com/

Comment: than simply embed a video file in background

Comment: that's not a video is just images
can not do Solocom images?

Comment: It's not a video that is an image sprite and they are basing the frame on the position of the mouse on the screen. http://larealpari.com/_/img/foto2.jpg

Comment: you can do that in css3 keyframes animation too

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 reasons why your script wasn't working.

1. Your CSS ~ jQuery element wasn't vaild, here is a vaild one:

   $(this).css({'background-Position': suma + "px 0px"}, "-10");
2. you had missing ); in the one of the }, so the function wasn't excute. ( `});` )